# How to make this function work so it takes a word from a list of words in an array?

Tags: php

I have this function to get random word from an array with words. I'm new to this game but it says variable $randomWord is not declared. when i add `print_r $word` it does work and prints a random word from the list.

this is the code i have so far:

```
$wrongGuesses = 0;

$randomWord = getRandomWord();

function getRandomWord()
{

    $wordList = ['boot', 'vliegtuig', 'fiets', 'helicopter', 'waterfiets', 'speedboot', 'step'];
    $random = rand(0, count($wordList) - 1);
    $word = $wordList[$random];
}
```

Comment: You can not call function before its declared. You need declare a function and after that you can call it. Call getRandomWord(); after function getRandomWord().

Comment: my editor says the $word variable is not declared and it is greyed out. if i add print_r $word under it then it does print the random word

Comment: if you have greyed out variable so it says variable is unused and might be redundant. In PHP you don't need variable declared before. Also you can change '$word =' to 'return' on last line.

Comment: Thanks for the info, return looks way better too

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by returning the value of `$word` like this:

```
function getRandomWord()
{

    $wordList = ['boot', 'vliegtuig', 'fiets', 'helicopter', 'waterfiets', 'speedboot', 'step'];
    $random = rand(0, count($wordList) - 1);
    $word = $wordList[$random];
    return $word;
}

$randomWord = getRandomWord();

print_r($randomWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

we've to return the value from the function to save it's value in $randomWord

```
$wrongGuesses = 0;
$randomWord = getRandomWord();

function getRandomWord()
{

    $wordList = ['boot', 'vliegtuig', 'fiets', 'helicopter', 'waterfiets', 'speedboot', 'step'];
    $random = rand(0, count($wordList) - 1);
    $word = $wordList[$random];
    return $word;
}
```